# Image going out of frame after run the apk

Tags: android

[here is xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNrpd.png)

[at android studio it seems like everything is ok. but after running the apk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p5ij.png)

Comment: Please move your XML code to the post body and format it by adding 4 trailing space. Also, read https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a question/ Right now it has very low quality and may be closed or removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking the preview for a device of different screen size than your phone.

To equally divide the images into 3 part in all devices, either use GridView/GridLayout or use LinearLayout with weights.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="3" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```